# Please help me identify this plant

Tags: species-identification

I got a plant from friend but neither he nor I know what it is. Could anyone help me identify this? Google reverse image search could only find aloe vera and other green plants that are obviously not this species. In addition, it looks like it is dying so any help on caring it is appreciated as well. 
[image: unknown plant]

Comment: It's some kind of succulent and it looks reasonably healthy.  Don't water it more than once a month.

Comment: Please add your location.

Comment: I would argue that house plants identification are off-topic here and such questions should rather be asked on [gardening.SE](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a cultivar of *Crassula ovata* or Jade Plant.  A little searching will reveal that there are many out there.  Yours looks a lot like a cultivar humorously called "ET's Fingers".  Search for "crassula ovata ets fingers jade" and you'll see many images.  I won't link to any since they aren't my pictures and the sites may not be available in the future.